# Redefinition of module 'dnssd' in Swift 3

Tags: xmpp, swift3, xcode8, xmppframework, dns-sd

I convert my project to Swift 3 recently and also installed XMPP framework.
 When I run the project , the error "**Redefinition of module 'dnssd'**" occurs. Here is my code of version **swift 2**...

```
module dnssd [system] {
header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/dns_sd.h"
export *
```

}

It converts automatically into **swift 3**.

```
module dnssd [system] [extern_c] {
    header "dns_sd.h"
    export *
}
```

When I try to edit something, it shows error "**Permission denied to edit this file.**" 
Please help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working by making the two modules different. Rename the module 'module.modulemap' to dnssd1.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my Podfile according to this solved this issue:

> # The version pushed to CocoaPods is very out of date, use master branch for now 
>   pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'
>   #pod 'XMPPFramework'

Comment: I tried your link. But it does not work and occurs error. The error is "Parse Issue" , Could not build module ‘Kiss XML’ NSXMLElement+XEP_0059.h.

Comment: Maybe you need to update Cocoa Pods version - sudo gem update cocoapods. My Podfile looks like this: 
platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!

target 'XXXXX' do
pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'
end

Comment: @Anfrey Volobuev, when I try your code, the compiler error occurs. The error is "Command / Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1 " .